# Web Service Request/Response matching and identification

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, webservice-client, webservices-client

I'm currently doing some development in C# consuming a webservice and I have created a Soap Extension to intercept raw request/response xml for logging purposes.

Ideally I am wanting to log each request/response in a separate log file, and was wondering if there is a unique id per request/response that I can use as part of the name for the log file so that no overwriting occurs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

I am consuming the web service in C# Winforms using .NET 2.0 (.NET 2.0 Is a requirement for us unfortunately).

Comment: What is the web service platform?

Comment: I'm consuming the web-service in C# (Winforms), I'm not sure what the webservice is being hosted on